# How to Specify a Delimiter in CSV file overriding List Separator Settings

Tags: csv

I have a csv file which is comma separated. But in my machine, the value in "List Separator" in "Regions and Language" option in control panel has value as semicolon (;). I can not change this semicolon value in setting due to other reasons.
When I try to save my file as csv after editing, it becomes semicolon separated due to the value in system settings. 
Is it possible to override the system setting by mentioning the delimiter value in the file itself ? So that when I save this file as csv, the separator still remains comma and not semicolon. Can I use sep=, somehow.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: I am using exel or notepad to open it

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a macro that saves the file

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "filename", FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=False
```

The latter (`local:=False`) makes sure the default separator (comma) is used instead of the one specified within the local settings.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Is it possible to set the local as false through some setting instead of macro?

Comment: Within the Advanced Excel Options, you can specify to override the system decimal and thousands separator (which may be necessary in case your default decimal separator is a command). I didn't find a way to override the field separator.